# Post jqgrid data to mvc3 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

How should I post the data entered in a jqgrid plugin to a MVC3 controller?

Thanks In Advance

Some code

Sending data to mvc3 controller

```
        var lineas = $("#articulosIngresadosTable").getRowData();
        var model = {
            ObraSocialId: $("#idObraSocialTextBox").val(),
            Lineas: lineas
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Nueva", "Factura")',
            data: model,
            success: function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); },
            dataType: "json"
        });
```

The controller

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Nueva(FacturaNuevaModel model)
    {
        return Json(model);
    }
```

The model

```
public class FacturaNuevaModel
{
    public string ObraSocialId { get; set; }
    public IList<Linea> Lineas { get; set; }
```

What I can't undestand is that I'm sending the same Json with Poster and works, but not whit jquery from the view

Using the post from the view, ObraSocialId is populated in the controller, and the Lineas collection have the items, but every property in Linea has a null value

Comment: Show your code first so that we can have a common base for discussion. Right now your question is very general.

Comment: @darin-dimitrov here is some code, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the contentType ...

Here is the working code

```
var lineas = $("#articulosIngresadosTable").getRowData();
var model = {
    ObraSocialId: $("#idObraSocialTextBox").val(),
    Lineas: lineas
};

var modelString = JSON.stringify(model);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("Nueva", "Factura")',
    data: modelString,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); }
});
```